# Intermittent Type Errors in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I am having very strange behavior in React. I will be working and after a while I'll see this error appear at console (with 'npm run start' running):

```
 Failed to compile.

 ./src/components/room.js TypeError: TYPES[value.type] is not a
 function
     at Array.forEach (native)
     at Array.forEach (native)
```

If I change nothing in the code, but I stop the app and re-run npm run start it works fine. I've also been getting "unexpected token" errors with the same behavior (restart the app and it starts working find with no changes to code). Has anyone else experienced this before?

I can't imagine it's related, but the only significant change since I started running into this is that I've upgraded to Mojave on my mac.

Adding code for reference.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AdventureMap from '../modules/map.js';

const ExitSpan = (props) => <span>{props.name}</span>

class Room extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {roomId: this.props.id, roomName: null, roomDescription: null, exitLabels:null, exits: null, message:''}
        this.mapModule = new AdventureMap();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadRoom(this.props.id);
    }

    async loadRoom(id) {
        let room = await this.mapModule.getRoom(id);
        let exits = await this.mapModule.getRoomExits(id);
        let exitLabels = exits.map(exit => {
            return <ExitSpan key={exit.target} name={exit.name} />
        });
        this.setState({roomId: room.id, roomName: room.name, roomDescription: room.description, exitLabels:exitLabels, exits:exits});
    }

    async processCommand(command)
    {
        let commandParts = command.split(' ');
        let commandResponse = null;
        switch (commandParts[0]) {
            case "walk":
                commandResponse = await this.mapModule.processWalkCommand(command, this.state.roomId);
            break;
            default:
                this.setState({message:'Sorry, I don\'t know how to ' + commandParts[0]});
            break;
        }

        if (commandResponse !== null) {
            switch (commandResponse.command) {
                case "loadroom":
                    this.loadRoom(commandResponse.args[0]);
                break;
                default:
                break;
            }

            if (commandResponse.message) {
                this.setState({message:commandResponse.message});
            }
        }
    }

    handleCommandChange(event) {
        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
            let command = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
            this.processCommand(command);
            event.target.value = '';
        }
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="console">
                <span>{this.state.message}</span>
                <div className="console-screen">
                    <div className="console-name">
                        {this.state.roomName}
                    </div>
                    <div className="console-description">
                        {this.state.roomDescription}
                    </div>
                    <div className="console-exits">
                        Exits:<br/><br/>
                            {this.state.exitLabels}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="text" className="command-input" onKeyPress={this.handleCommandChange.bind(this)} placeholder="> enter command" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Room;
```

Again though, this happens off and on with no changes to the code. Also, the unexpected token error is sometimes thrown on this line:

```
const ExitSpan = (props) => <span>{props.name}</span>
```

Comment: Please share relevant code

Comment: There is no relevant code. This appears and disappears with no changes to code.

Comment: Really? It’s an issue in room.js component means you do not have concrete functionality so obviously to help you you need to share that component code and that’s why you get no response from others

Comment: Please share your room.js code, it seems there's some issue.

Comment: I've added the code.

Comment: A small update. Resaving the file I'm editing (no changes) sometimes fixes it, but not always. I'm wondering if it's something to do with how it is detecting file changes and reading them in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this here for anyone who runs into this problem in the future:  There was something wrong with npm that was causing this. I later ran into other problems and eventually tried to upgrade npm and all of npm completely stopped working. I reinstalled it and haven't run into any problems since.